# How users flag in chat or react to flags is totally broken

Tags: discussion, flags, chat

We talked about the latest changes in Python and if we share the view on  "offensive" words like master and slave (in short nobody seemed to agree).

So I was also making a sarcastic statement about other terms and phrases that seem to be totally offensive when ripped out of context. And to absolutely no surprise this message was flagged. 5 times. Then someone seems to have removed the message manually as I was muted for 30 minutes.

As past experiences also have shown people tend to simply press "valid" without even checking the context I suggest we change the way flags can be agreed on: You have to join the room and can validate or invalidate the flag there. Not from the outside but being forced to see the context first.

(If the tags are wrong, please remove the edit :P)

[image]

Comment: Is having a sudden influx of people to the room desirable?

Comment: I agree, but at least they should see the transcript. Like in the review area where you see the original as well and not only the changed part.

Comment: I suppose the influx of people could be avoided by presenting them part of the transcript instead of a single message.

Comment: @TimCastelijns: I agree, but how much? Often enough, the relevant context isn't in the previous 3 messages.

Comment: @JonClements Using Moneyball tactics, I'd say yeah, certainly desirable for the health of the room longterm. Just like in the old Sierra Studios games Caesar III and Pharaoh and Zeus, on your demographics page you always wanna see "people are coming, or want to come, to your city" :-) Growth is key. Even Stack Overflow the company would have to agree with that!

Comment: Good grief people are getting sensitive. No way that comment should have been flagged. Even without context at *worst* it was a poor attempt at humor; and could have been a totally valid comment (ie, this is *exactly* what a watchdog does).

Comment: @Cerbrus I would suggest the 3 previous and 3 following (these are equally important). Fewer might be too few and more might be too many. Indeed it won't always be enough but it would already be much better than 0. Perhaps with a link to the full transcript with the flagged message highlighted for full context.

Comment: If you want more context it's not hard to view the transcript. While it would be good if more people did that before voting on flags I don't think they should be _forced_ to view the transcript.

Comment: @PM2Ring: As much as I'd like that to be, we now have hard evidence otherwise. People needed the transcript on this one and didn't know they needed it.

Comment: I'd say that this is a problem with chat communication of all kinds (on SO or otherwise): it encourages the divorcing of statement from context. Unless you put the context into every message, there is nothing you can do to ensure that anyone who sees one message will understand the context it was intended to be in. So if someone (or several someones) happen to jump in between two messages you're writing, readers will see the second message with less of the context of the first. That's just the nature of chat. If you're going to say something like that, make sure the context is in the message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203346/flags-in-chat-are-defective-by-design

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309659/244695

Comment: Obviously, the buttons should be labeled “`offensive`”, “`not offensive`”, and “`not sure`”. Buttons should say what say mean, not requiring additional effort like with “`valid`” (what is valid, the message or the flag?). That’s an old UI sin, like labeling a button “`proceed`” (with terminating the application). In Germany, we even have a law for that, i.e. the button leading to buying something must be explicitly labeled as such, not be ambiguous like “Ok” or “Proceed”… In that regard, consider even “`Offensive, Do Delete`” as label, to remind the user at the consequences of this choice.

Comment: The flag is "**Spam** / Offensive". Just something to be mentioned when relabeling the buttons as @Holger suggested (eventhough I don't think I have seen spam in chat so far).

Comment: This wouldn't be an issue if "offensive" wasn't a reason to censor people. Let users act like adults and self moderate. Let mods remove disruptive spam. There, I solved the whole dilemma.

Comment: Ohh I get it, it's a joke about parents killing their children! Haha! Yes it shouldn't have been flagged, but yes, it's also a joke in bad taste...

Comment: @dwirony that's why it's funny though

Comment: @dwirony: "bad taste" is subjective, and not a flaggable offense.

Answer (score 39):

It may be helpful to make a room owners' vote on such flags count for (much) more than a "normal" vote.

Room Owners are the ones responsible for keeping the room "in line". They're familiar with the room's culture and are generally uniquely qualified to judge a chat flag's validity.

Should valid flags be cancelled by ROs, then there's always the option to add a custom moderator flag, so the ROs can be corrected.

Of course, this would require ROs to be able to see flags in their rooms, regardless of how much rep they have.

Comment: In that case it would already help if room owners in general had the right to vote or even see the flag. With 2.342 rep being a room owner in the Java room (where it is usualy rather quiet) I had a few occurences where I had to be informed by other users that a message got flagged. If roomowners are responsible for moderating the room, they should have all the tools for doing so that are accessible for other with more reputation.

Comment: Agreed. I'll add that into my post.

Comment: One issue I see with this is if the RO's don't care they could invalidate the flag even if it really is valid.  We've had history of this before where RO's perpetuate /allow not nice behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver: That's where moderator flags come in. It wouldn't be the first time for a room to get closed down due to ROs not keeping order.

Answer (score 15):

We considered the idea of allowing flags some time to 'soak' in any given room prior to being shown outside of the room, and only showing them outside of the room *if nobody in the room acted on them* in a reasonable amount of time. This allowed for:

1. Much more granular control by room owners (they could squash something prior to it circulating to all 10k users)
2. There's a *far* less chance that something benign but questionable if taken out of context would be picked up, well, *out of context*.

We basically had that spec written, and then .. some bad things happened in chat. A few situations where room owners *and some very high rep users* weren't only complacent when it came to allowing and encouraging pretty sketchy behavior, they were also actively working to *cover it up*.

Had we implemented what we were considering, it's unlikely that this stuff would have surfaced, and ... that would have been *really darn bad (TM)*.

Since we've *seen* the worst anticipated behavior, we have to account for it, and that makes this a little hairy. We're open to ideas, for the *most* part we strike a pretty good balance with the system we have, but when it goes wrong (in either direction: stuff getting piled on that's benign, or awful stuff not getting flagged) it tends to go *really* wrong.

Even the simplest idea like *don't show flags out of the room on stuff written by 10k+ users* breaks because *we've seen 10k+ users actively try to cover bad things up.* I think we're even open to putting additional work on employees here, but we can't count on someone being around 24/7, so there's always going to be some need for the system to just ask anyone it can find as a failover (at least).

We're open to ideas that take the above into account. I've disliked how this works since the day we launched chat; we've just yet to come up with anything better that doesn't open the door for awful even wider.

Comment: Maybe the popup should only say: *something is flagged, visit the transcript for context* (no more buttons for valid, invalid, unsure) and then on *only* the transcript page you allow 10K-ers to click [valid], [unsure] , [invalid] on the flagged message. That at least forces them to take context into account.

Comment: Tim - given that chat.SO and chat.SE are completely separate beasts (26 moderators vs hundreds and rooms for a topic vs rooms for a site etc...) - and SO generally has very experienced users in chat as well as moderators that know the rooms, know the people, know the troublemakers and the rooms/people know the moderators (whether they like 'em or not :p) could the chat.SO system diverge in the codebase slightly from the other two? Not massively, but that might give some freedom to experiment a little bit?

Comment: I've got a misty idea forming but I think it depends on being able to do that - probably not ideal but if a solution can't be found to work network wide but it can on SO - worth a try?

Comment: Flag the flags queue? *.*

Comment: @JonClements there is definitely a disconnect between the two chat cultures, but I honestly don't know which way it should slide.

Comment: At the absolute bare minimum just add "Please understand the context of the message before voting [transcript link]" to the prompt. It's... something.

Comment: I agree that it would already help if there was a link to the transcript. Instead, you have a link to the user and to the room (which makes you join the room). Neither of that is really helpful.

Comment: _"We've seen 10k+ users actively try to cover bad things up."_ Then close those rooms. As it is right now, chat flags flags don't work. The added responsibility Room Owners would get can be balanced with moderator flags where the responsibility is abused.

Comment: Perhaps you could simply remove the mute aspect from disputed flags as long as that user hasn't been flagged in the last 24 hours

Answer (score 11):

I saw that one live*. I now request that a moderator go restore that chat entry in its proper place in the transcript.

That interface is bad. Need to show previous and next message by the same user at the absolute least. You will still get problems w/o half a page of transcript though.

*I'm pretty sure I actually followed a transcript link in the short window it could be seen because I never joined the room.